# Can OEIS be used for searching of sequences of pairs?

Tags: sequences-and-series, oeis

As in title:
Does oeis.org store sequences made of pairs of integers, like:
$$(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...,$$

If so, then how can I search for one?

Comment: What would be the point of that? Your question is unclear as it stands. Please clarify.

Comment: I have a sequence of pairs and i want to find out if anybody studied this sequence before. I am especialy interested in its formula. If it was normal sequence, like 1,1,2,3,5,8,... then i would search for it in oeis, but this one is made of pairs, so I would like to know if one can search for pairs's sequences in oeis

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the OEIS contains sequences of pairs, triples, etc. Generally they are encoded as several sequences. For example, the Bernouli numbers are [A027641](https://oeis.org/A027641)/[A027642](https://oeis.org/A027642) and the solutions (x,y) of $x^2+(x+31)^2=y^2$ are ([A118674](https://oeis.org/A118674), [A157646](https://oeis.org/A157646)). Some rare sequences encode pairs as (a(1), a(2)), (a(3), a(4)), etc.

Collections of sequences are often given as a two-dimensional table read by antidiagonals.

If you like, give me your sequence (in a comment) and I'll see if it's in the OEIS.

Comment: So what is the format for such a query? I've tried (a,b),(c,d),..., and it dont work

Comment: To find (a,b), (c,d), (e,f), ... I would first search for a,c,e and b,d,f (ideally giving 10+ terms for each), then I'd try a,b,c,d,e,f, then I might try individual large terms in case they're encoded in a funny way. Again, I'm happy to help if you give me your terms, I have long experience with the encyclopedia.

Comment: The problem is that this sequence is from algorithmic contest. I dont wont to make it public

Comment: @yolo_swaggins1337 Well, good luck then.